# Malformatted confirmation link

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, newsletter, subscription

I tried to subscribe to a tag on SU, I've got the confirmation mail but the link renders with `)###` appended to it in Plain-Text Mode, which will result in a 404 not found.

`###[Confirm Subscription](http://stackexchange.com/filters/email-confirm/123456)###`

I'm using Opera Mail client.

## Suggestions:

- Adding a space in between solves the issue without breaking the markdown.
- Offering an option for receiving newsletters as PlainText.

Comment: Great .. I voted to close this question, I thought i can move it to meta.StackOverflow.com

Comment: You can flag it for moderator attention to migrate it.

Comment: @Revolter it's perfectly OK to ask questions that _apply_ to the whole network here on Meta Super User. I've dismissed your flag for now, but if you _really, really_ want to move it to MSO, then flag it again and we can do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

The confirmation emails appear to be sent as plain text with an HTML copy attached (as is typical for HTML emails); if your email client has been set to display HTML emails you will see that version instead.

The plain text version is [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) formatted. Yes, that [same thing Stack Exchange uses](https://meta.superuser.com/editing-help). Markdown is designed to be readable when sent as plain text, and I assume some email clients will render it formatted properly too.

What you are seeing is a Markdown [inline link](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link) enclosed in a [header](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#header). It's perfectly valid. What's likely actually happening is **your mail client is interpreting the `http://ValidURICharacters` as a link**, and included the `)###` in it. It is both technically valid Markdown and a technically valid URI, so...

An easy fix for you is to use a HTML or Markdown compatible email client (or enable it if you have it disabled). Or you can copy and paste the URL manually; after all, with plain text emails, the clickable link is merely a convenience provided by your email client.

---

```
###[Confirm Subscription](http://stackexchange.com/filters/email-confirm/123456)###
```

renders as

#### [Confirm Subscription](http://stackexchange.com/filters/email-confirm/123456)

in Markdown

---

<sup>As an aside, Thunderbird appears to highlight the link without the `)###` when viewing in plain text mode. I'm pretty sure that's technically incorrect, but it probably works more often.</sup>

Comment: it works fine when I use HTML, I only prefer reading my emails as plain text and without extra stuffs (I think I'm not the only one). actually separating the )### from the link with a blank space fixes the problem and without breaking the Markdown. I don't know if this the proper way to report bugs.

Comment: I wouldn't really consider it a *bug* as such, since everything is technically valid. It's really just those plain text email clients that want to make things that 'look like links' clickable. Perhaps others may have a differing opinion, or a SE team member will give an official word on this (you may have more success on the http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ site, which is the network wide meta - also, try giving a specific suggestion, such as adding the space).

Comment: I guess you could also request an option (on the user profile/tag subscription page) to send emails as non-Markdown plain text.